# Is there a public sound bank of the IPA?

Tags: ipa, phones, speech-synthesis, spoken-language

I'm looking for a comprehensive audio database of the IPA, spoken by the same individual. I realize the this restriction may not include the full set of the IPA and I'm willing to settle on the largest subset. The database needs to be free to mix in with other open-source projects, so the examples found in:

http://web.uvic.ca/ling/resources/ipa/handbook_downloads.htm

would not work. The closest I've found is the collection of Wikipedia phones, like the [voiced bilabial fricative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Voiced_bilabial_fricative.ogg), but these are spoken by different individuals.

Comment: I've been looking for something like this too, especially to hear the difference between certain vowels like [o] and [ɔ].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

York University (Ontario, Canada) has a site where you can hear all the IPA sounds: http://www.yorku.ca/earmstro/ipa/